# How can I show end of Label in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there any way how can style my Label in Xamarin.Forms to expand in row to the space it really needs (even beyond screens width) and then show the end of it?

To explain it better, here is the picture of two situations:

[image: screen with two Label controls]

Let's asume that black box are the screen bounds. Blue and red boxes are Label's bounds. **Both** Labels has set Text property to "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z".

Label in blue box is pretty easy and standard to achieve.

My concerns is regarding the Label in red box. Can this be done through XAML or need some code-behind calculations and setting?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  If the text is too long for the label, do you want it to scroll?  Shrink?  Wrap?  Truncate?  Or what?

Comment: Sorry about ambiguousness. The Label is horizontally stretched and overflowing screen's width and I want to show the ending of that Label and not the beginning. Better explained or still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [LineBreakMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping) property

```
<Label LineBreakMode="HeadTruncation" ... />
```

Comment: Nearly perfect, only those dots at the begining are not wanted in my case. Is there any chance to remove them?

Comment: No idea.  Look at the different options available in the docs.  Otherwise you probably need a custom control or renderer

Comment: Seems, that in that case it needs custom "renderer", but I will accept this as an Answer. Thank you Jason!